# Why isn't Tcl detecting any `readable` event when esbuild is in watch or serve mode?

Tags: tcl, stdout, event-loop, esbuild

I'm trying to drive esbuild (a CLI for web dev) in an event loop as part of a cross-platform build script for my project. Of course, I could have run the CLI directly in a terminal, like this:

```
esbuild init.js --bundle --outdir=build --watch --servedir=build
```

, but having an all-in-one script for all dev tasks is nice, and I want to learn more about Tcl scripting.

Now in blocking mode (using `exec`), there's no problem in getting the output, except for the (common?) oddity that esbuild returns with exit code 1 even if there's no error. However, for long-running tasks like "watch" or "serve", I need to set up an event loop, right? But I'm surprised that while running, esbuild never emits anything that Tcl regards as "readable", yet when invoked from the terminal directly, the CLI displays its output (messages like script rebuild or page reload) perfectly fine. Here's a script to demo the situation:

```
proc read_output {cid} {
    global loopdone

    puts {[read_output] I got sth!}

    if {[catch {read $cid} content] || [chan eof $cid]} {
        chan configure $cid -blocking 1

        catch {close $cid} msg
        puts {subproc is done}
        puts $msg

        set loopdone 1
        return
    } else {
        puts $content
    }
}

set dev build/dev

set cid [open "|esbuild init.js --bundle --outdir=$dev --watch --servedir=$dev" r]
# set cid [open "|esbuild init.js --bundle --outdir=$dev" r]

chan configure $cid \
    -translation lf \
    -buffering line \
    -blocking 0

chan event $cid readable "read_output $cid"

puts "entering event loop..."

vwait loopdone

puts "loop ended"
```

When running, the script output will be stuck at "entering event loop..." forever, which means the event handler for `readable` is never called!

However, if esbuild is not in watch or serve mode (as in the second `open` command that is commented out), the event handler is triggered correctly:

```
entering event loop...
[read_output] I got sth!
subproc is done

  build\dev\init.js  9.4kb

Done in 7ms
loop ended
```

I also tried a few things, such as using different access modes for the `open` command, and different options for `chan configure`, like `-buffering`. But so far none seemed to have an effect.

Thank you very much for reading this.

Comment: Is `esbuild` writing to `stdout` and `stderr`? If both, then make sure to add `2>@1` to your open call: `open |[list esbuild init.js --bundle --outdir=$dev --watch --servedir=$dev 2>@1] r`.

Comment: Seems like `stderr` is important in your scenario: https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/2009

Comment: Either merge the channels (as described above) or use `chan pipe` and redirection to make a way to capture the diagnostics separately.

Comment: @mrcalvin I followed your advice, and indeed that was precisely the solution! So thanks a lot for pointing it out, and also finding the relevant discussion from esbuild issues. I was suspecting that the "silence" was due to not looking at the right channel, but wasn't aware of a way to configure that. For future readers, the manual page for [exec](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm) has all the details about IO redirection syntax.

Comment: @treslumen Please self-answer your question, to close this one properly for future readers.

Comment: @mrcalvin Done. Please feel free to let me know if you find anything that can be improved? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

As noted by mrcalvin in the question comments, the reason why the channel was silent was that esbuild uses *stderr* for all informational output, including non-error messages, while always dedicating stdout to the build resultant. The solution is therefore to use IO redirection, in particular, to redirect standard error to the command result, we use the `2>@1` operator. For instance,

```
open |[list esbuild init.js --bundle --outdir=$dir --servedir=$dir 2>@1] r
```

Alternatively, as noted by Donal Fellows, `chan pipe` ([manual page](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/chan.htm#M29)) can be used to redirect stderr or stdout independently from each other, as it creates a standalone pair of channels to set up the redirection that is separate from the configuration of the main channel as returned by `open`.

Here is a demo script, where we only care about the stderr:

```
proc read_stderr {cid} {
    global loopdone

    if {[catch {gets $cid line} len] || [chan eof $cid]} {
        chan configure $cid -blocking 1

        catch {close $cid} msg
        puts "subproc is done"
        puts $msg

        set loopdone 1
        return
    } elseif {$len >= 0} {
        puts $line
    }
}

set dir build/dev

lassign [chan pipe] rchan wchan
open |[list esbuild init.js --bundle --outdir=$dir --servedir=$dir 2>@ $wchan] r
catch {close $wchan}

chan configure $rchan -translation lf -buffering line -blocking 0
chan event $rchan readable [list read_stderr $rchan]

puts "entering event loop..."
vwait loopdone
puts "loop ended"
```

Again, thank you both for your help! I learned something cool.

---

A comment on a minor point raised in the question:

> Now in blocking mode (using `exec`), there's no problem in getting the output, except for the (common?) oddity that esbuild returns with exit code 1 even if there's no error.

Since now we know esbuild uses stderr even for non-error message output, an alternative explanation of this odd behavior is that esbuild does correctly return the normal exit code (0) when there is no error, but because by default, `exec` will raise an error as long as a subprocess outputs anything to stderr, we end up getting an error return code (1) from Tcl (but not necessarily from the subprocess itself).

One way to neutralize this false positive is to use `try...trap {NONE}` ([manual page](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/try.htm)), which is a streamlined way of looking at the `-errorcode` value that you'd otherwise have to do explicitly using `catch`. However, now we know the cause of this false positive, we can simply use `exec -ignorestderr` so that Tcl no longer regards the mere existence of stderr output as an error case.

For example, we can create a handy proc for calling esbuild (in blocking mode):

```
proc esbuild {args} {
    exec -ignorestderr esbuild {*}$args
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing that up. I didn't have time to do it when I posted the comment.

Comment: @DonalFellows Thank you for taking the time to help out, on both the question and the answer:) I just added a comment about a minor point mentioned in the question. But I'm still not sure, when we get an error in Tcl, is there a way to tell whether the subprocess truly returns a non-zero exit code, or it actually does "exit 0", but outputs to stderr (and we are not using `-ignorestderr`)? I mean we can deduce it by enabling `-ignorestderr` and then see if the error goes away, but is there a way to check the true exit code in Tcl directly?

Comment: Turns out, the manual page for [exec](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm#M27) has a code example for just that! When a subprocess gives a non-zero exit code, it can be extracted from the `-errorcode` value in the form of e.g. `{CHILDSTATUS 1234 1}`, where the 2nd element is the process ID, and the 3rd is the exit code.